# Voltage Supply Circuit

Tags: power-supply, diodes, analog

I am trying to supply my circuit from this part. I have two different supplies which are VUSB_5V and VORG_5V. My aim is when one of two comes to circuit, this supply does not go to other one or effect it to prevent a dangerous situation. If both supplies are available, the bigger one should become to VCC_5V. For this reason, i put tho didodes. However, when i supply one of these only with 5V, i am measuring approximately 5V at the other's while there is a diode before it.

For example, if there is only VUSB_5V is supplying, i measure voltage of C17 is 4.9V. I observed another interesting thing that when i am measuring voltage with multimeter, voltage is increasing at TP9 until 4.9V. Voltage on D1 is approximately 0.2V.

I am thinking to change diodes and adding pull down before didodes. What can be the reason of this situation and how can i solve this?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: We don't share opinions here, we answer questions. Please ask a question. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't actually see a question, but all diodes have leakage current. If there's nothing connected to one of the supply inputs the leakage current will slowly charge the caps until they reach a steady state voltage close to the other supply voltage.  If that's a problem, you could add some resistance before each diode.

If you were to connect your other supply it's likely there would be enough impedance even when it's off so that the voltage wouldn't rise.

Comment: Thank you so much. VORG_5V will come from Raspberry Pi to supply my circuit. My aim is if i supply my circuit just from USB connector, this current does not go to Raspberry Pi. I am trying to prevent it.

Comment: A 100k or 1Meg ohm pull-down would be more useful in preventing the anode side of the unpowered dioded reaching high voltage than would a series resistor.

Comment: When i added 1M pull down resistor i observed 4.5V on LTSpice and when i added 1k i observed 0.049V at there. Is it logical? I did not try these on board. Serial resistor did not change the voltage on simulation.

Comment: Do you think that 1k is enough?

Comment: The PMEG3030 you selected is a Schottky, which is good, but it's an extremely leaky Schottky with 5mA of reverse current (max, 30V) at 25C.  Could get much worse at high temperature.  So 1K may not be enough if you want to guarantee that there's no voltage on the inactive supply.  (Though why that's important I'm not sure I understand.)

Comment: You mean a parallel and less resistor and series and bigger one? Will it be dangerous if there is a voltage at inactive supply?

Comment: When i put 1k shunt in front of the diodes, the problem was solved. Thank you.